# How to run mysql query as other user

Tags: mysql, bash, su

I have a mysql command that I am able to execute as my user `testuser`. Root does not have access to the db.

I'm creating a startup script which runs as `root`, but I need to run the query from above as `testuser` during this script. I tried this:

```
sudo -u testuser "mysql -D keystone -e "UPDATE endpoint SET url=REPLACE(url, '$OLD_IP', '$HOST_IP');""
```

But I get the error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Does anyone know where my syntax is off?

Solution was no quotes around entire mysql command:

```
sudo -u testuser mysql -D keystone -e "UPDATE endpoint SET url=REPLACE(url, '$OLD_IP', '$HOST_IP');"
```

Comment: try `mysql -u testuser`

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

That mysql user doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `"` is closing the string that begins at `mysql`, try quoting the inner quoted string:

```
sudo -u testuser "mysql -D keystone -e \"UPDATE endpoint SET url=REPLACE(url, '$OLD_IP', '$HOST_IP');\""
```